# How can I make an element be next to multiple other elements while sharing a parent container?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I have an unknown amount of elements and next to them they need to have an element always next to them like this:

```
╔═══════╦═══╗
║       ║   ║
╠═══════╣   ║
║       ║   ║
╠═══════╣   ║
║       ║   ║
╠═══════╣   ║
║       ║   ║
╚═══════╩═══╝
```

They can't be two separate containers, my CSS is already quite complex and I'm working with other people as well so it would be quite difficult to change it everywhere.

I tried setting `grid-row` on the right element to `1 / -1`, but you can only use negative values if you have explicity set `grid-template-rows`, but I don't know how many columns there are.

Something else I tried was using a CSS counter to set either `grid-row-end: counter(count)` or setting `grid-template-rows: repeat(counter(count), auto)`, but it doesn't output a number.

What can I do? Should I just make it be two separate containers? Using JavaScript is not a great solution either.

Edit: a strange solution that isn't very reliable, but should work in most situations assuming the rest of the layout is known, you can set `grid-column: 1 / span 99`. I tried doing `1 / 99` before but this is better and doesn't create new rows.

Comment: "but you can only use negative values if you have explicity set grid-template-columns" — That's not correct. The whole point of `1/-1` is that it works how ever many rows/columns there are. Anyhow, the easy option here is to have another gird container in the left side with multiple rows.

Comment: @ralph.m I meant `grid-template-rows` not columns. It does work no matter how many columns there are, but only when you explicity set the amount. Trust me, I tried it. Clicking on a grid element also shows that -1 is the same as 1 and no other negative numbers work. If you don't believe me try it yourself. On MDN: `Note: You can also use the value -1 to target the end column or row line, then count inwards from the end using negative values. Note also that lines count always from the edges of the explicit grid, not the implicit grid.`

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1: With two containers**

You can achieve the same output using `flexbox`. You can split your container into two columns `left` and `right`, and the split your `left` container into four smaller containers. I added an example bellow with fixed dimensions just for referencing. Hope that helps.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left, .right {
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right {
    width: 30%;
}

.left {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.first-row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.second-row {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.third-row {
  border: 1px solid purple;
}
.fourth-row {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="row first-row"></div>
    <div class="row second-row"></div>
    <div class="row third-row"></div>
    <div class="row fourth-row"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2: With One container** (Not recommended)

You can achieve that also with one container but I do not recommend it because as you say you the boxes on the left will be dynamic. Here is any example but with fixed elements and fixed heights.

I would suggestion switching to two separate containers since it is a more clear layout for what you want to achieve.

```css
.container { 
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
    width: 70%;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    float: left;
}

.fifth-row {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.first-row {
    border: 1px solid blue;
 }

.second-row {
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.third-row {
    border: 1px solid purple;
}

.fourth-row {
    border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row first-row"></div>
    <div class="row second-row"></div>
    <div class="row third-row"></div>
    <div class="row fourth-row"></div>
    <div class="fifth-row"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know you can do that, my question is if there's a way to do it without two separate containers.

Comment: Also setting `width: 100%` is unneccessary on a block element and can cause the page to overflow since it doesn't account for the scrollbar, `flex-grow` to 3 or 7 better than setting width directly because it will always take up the correct amount of space and not overflow or underflow and you can use `nth-child` instead of setting a class for each element manually

Comment: @s456 I edited my answer with another solution, but I wouldn't recommend it. If possible consider switching into two separate containers since it is a more clear layout for what you want to achieve.